# Rooted Moto Z2 Play seemingly bricked after accidental OTA update. Any chance to save it?

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, fastboot, unbricking, motorola-moto-z2-play

I have had my Z2 Play for half a year, and soon after I got it I unlocked the bootloader with Motorola's official method, installed TWRP, rooted it with Magisk and installed Xposed Framework.  I was on Nougat all the time and used it happily. A few months ago it started repeatedly asking to OTA update, but I just ignored the messages. Then one day, I must have accidentally pressed something, because I think it tried to update. I got a message that the update failed or something like that.

The phone gradually got worse after that, randomly rebooting into TWRP. I could somehow get it to boot Android by going to the bootloader and chosing "factory mode" but mostly the modem would not work at all and the phone would not be usable.

Trying to solve it, I decided to flash a whole ROM, hoping to remove all of the damage done by the botchered update. Since I already had unlocked my bootloader and TWRP, I decided to just flash a custom ROM, since I did not know if flashing stock would work with TWRP. I found some of the custom ROMs on XDA, and tried to flash them with TWRP. However, flashing would not work. I got some error code 255. I am attaching a screenshot of the error.

[image]

I tried both flashing via the adb sideload method via my Mac and via USB OTG (flash drive) but I got the same result for both.

Having seen this, I decided to try to relock the bootloader and restore stock firmware. I tried following [this tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/z2-play/how-to/stock-stock-firmware-t3630997). However, that did not seem to work. Here is my fastboot output:

```
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot devices
ZY224BLVMC  fastboot
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fasboot oem lock begin
-bash: ./fasboot: No such file or directory
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ fastboot oem lock begin
-bash: fastboot: command not found
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot oem lock begin
(bootloader) WARNING: This command erases all user data.
(bootloader) Please re-run this command to continue.
OKAY [  0.003s]
Finished. Total time: 0.005s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot oem lock begin
(bootloader) Flash valid Android images now
(bootloader) Then re-run this command to lock
OKAY [  0.018s]
Finished. Total time: 0.018s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash partition gpt.bin
(bootloader) has-slot:partition: not found
Sending 'partition' (45 KB)                        OKAY [  0.008s]
Writing 'partition'                                (bootloader) Validating 'gpt.default.xml'
(bootloader) Security version downgrade
(bootloader) Image primary_gpt failed validation
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
(bootloader) Cancelling 'gpt.default.xml'
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 0.264s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ sudo fastboot flash partition gpt.bin
Password:
sudo: fastboot: command not found
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ sudo ./fastboot flash partition gpt.bin 
(bootloader) has-slot:partition: not found
Sending 'partition' (45 KB)                        OKAY [  0.005s]
Writing 'partition'                                (bootloader) Validating 'gpt.default.xml'
(bootloader) Security version downgrade
(bootloader) Image primary_gpt failed validation
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
(bootloader) Cancelling 'gpt.default.xml'
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 0.259s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash bootloader bootloader.img
(bootloader) has-slot:bootloader: not found
Sending 'bootloader' (5115 KB)                     OKAY [  0.209s]
Writing 'bootloader'                               (bootloader) Validating 'bootloader.default.xml'
(bootloader) Committing 'bootloader.default.xml'
(bootloader) - flashing 'emmc_appsboot.mbn' to 'aboot'
(bootloader) - flashing 'rpm.mbn' to 'rpm'
(bootloader) - flashing 'tz.mbn' to 'tz'
(bootloader) - flashing 'devcfg.mbn' to 'devcfg'
(bootloader) - flashing 'cmnlib.mbn' to 'cmnlib'
(bootloader) - flashing 'cmnlib64.mbn' to 'cmnlib64'
(bootloader) - flashing 'keymaster.mbn' to 'keymaster'
(bootloader) - flashing 'prov.mbn' to 'prov'
(bootloader) - flashing 'sbl1.mbn' to 'sbl1'
OKAY [  0.548s]
Finished. Total time: 0.943s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash logo logo.bin
(bootloader) has-slot:logo: not found
Sending 'logo' (2192 KB)                           OKAY [  0.093s]
Writing 'logo'                                     OKAY [  0.066s]
Finished. Total time: 0.344s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash recovery recovery.img  
(bootloader) has-slot:recovery: not found
Sending 'recovery' (20580 KB)                      OKAY [  0.838s]
Writing 'recovery'                                 (bootloader) Security version downgrade
(bootloader) Image recovery failed validation
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 1.234s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash recovery recovery.img 
(bootloader) has-slot:recovery: not found
Sending 'recovery' (20580 KB)                      OKAY [  0.729s]
Writing 'recovery'                                 (bootloader) Security version downgrade
(bootloader) Image recovery failed validation
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 1.125s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash dsp adspso.bin
(bootloader) has-slot:dsp: not found
Sending 'dsp' (16384 KB)                           OKAY [  0.667s]
Writing 'dsp'                                      OKAY [  0.132s]
Finished. Total time: 0.984s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash oem oem.img 
(bootloader) has-slot:oem: not found
Sending 'oem' (232923 KB)                          OKAY [ 10.302s]
Writing 'oem'                                      (bootloader) Security version downgrade
(bootloader) Image o failed validation
(bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 10.554s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0
(bootloader) has-slot:system: not found
Sending 'system' (517135 KB)                       OKAY [ 20.549s]
Writing 'system'                                   (bootloader) Security version downgrade
(bootloader) Image s failed validation
(bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1
(bootloader) has-slot:system: not found
Sending 'system' (522979 KB)                       OKAY [ 20.458s]
Writing 'system'                                   (bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 20.674s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2
(bootloader) has-slot:system: not found
Sending 'system' (524215 KB)                       OKAY [ 20.487s]
Writing 'system'                                   (bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 20.704s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.3
(bootloader) has-slot:system: not found
Sending 'system' (521087 KB)                       OKAY [ 19.126s]
Writing 'system'                                   (bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 19.330s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.4
(bootloader) has-slot:system: not found
Sending 'system' (518083 KB)                       OKAY [ 19.082s]
Writing 'system'                                   (bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 19.295s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.5
(bootloader) has-slot:system: not found
Sending 'system' (515569 KB)                       OKAY [ 18.974s]
Writing 'system'                                   (bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 19.192s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.6
(bootloader) has-slot:system: not found
Sending 'system' (250209 KB)                       OKAY [  9.380s]
Writing 'system'                                   (bootloader) Invalid signed image
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 9.579s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.7
(bootloader) has-slot:system: not found
fastboot: error: cannot load 'system.img_sparsechunk.7': No such file or directory
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin 
(bootloader) has-slot:modem: not found
Sending 'modem' (75092 KB)                         OKAY [  2.888s]
Writing 'modem'                                    OKAY [  1.878s]
Finished. Total time: 4.954s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot erase modemst1
(bootloader) has-slot:modemst1: not found
Erasing 'modemst1'                                 OKAY [  0.020s]
Finished. Total time: 0.210s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot erase modemst2
(bootloader) has-slot:modemst2: not found
Erasing 'modemst2'                                 OKAY [  0.020s]
Finished. Total time: 0.210s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn 
(bootloader) has-slot:fsg: not found
Sending 'fsg' (2932 KB)                            OKAY [  0.114s]
Writing 'fsg'                                      OKAY [  0.065s]
Finished. Total time: 0.364s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot erase cache
(bootloader) has-slot:cache: not found
Erasing 'cache'                                    OKAY [  0.016s]
Finished. Total time: 0.206s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot erase userdata
(bootloader) has-slot:userdata: not found
Erasing 'userdata'                                 OKAY [  2.252s]
Finished. Total time: 2.442s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot erase customize
(bootloader) has-slot:customize: not found
Erasing 'customize'                                (bootloader) Permission denied
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 0.194s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot erase customize
(bootloader) has-slot:customize: not found
Erasing 'customize'                                (bootloader) Permission denied
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 0.194s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot erase clogo
(bootloader) has-slot:clogo: not found
Erasing 'clogo'                                    (bootloader) Permission denied
FAILED (remote failure)
Finished. Total time: 0.192s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot oem lock
(bootloader) Still require signed boot.img
OKAY [  0.003s]
Finished. Total time: 0.003s
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot reboot
Rebooting                                          
Finished. Total time: 0.005s
```

This seemed to do nothing to my device. I wondered if maybe the bootloader was in some sort of locked/unlocked limbo, so I tried to unlock the bootloader again using the key I got from Moto by email. That did not work either.

```
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot oem unlock THECODEFORMYDEVICE
(bootloader) invalid boot state
OKAY [  0.005s]
Finished. Total time: 0.008s
```

So I seem to be getting nowhere. There has to be some way to totally wipe everything, to get a fresh start? I do not care if I have to restore stock firmware, stock bootloader, whatever. I just want to be able to at least use my phone somehow. Is my device totally bricked? Is there nothing I can do?

I used adb and fastboot on macOS High Sierra.

At the request of @acejavelin, I am posting some more information:

```
Pals-MacBook-Air:platform-tools Fiksdal$ ./fastboot getvar all
(bootloader) version: 0.5
(bootloader) version-bootloader: moto-msm8953-C0.C7
(bootloader) product: albus
(bootloader) board: albus
(bootloader) secure: yes
(bootloader) hwrev: P4
(bootloader) radio: 3
(bootloader) storage-type: emmc
(bootloader) emmc: 64GB SKHYNIX HCG8a4 RV=08 PV=A2 FV=00000000000000A2
(bootloader) ram: 4GB SKHYNIX LP3 DIE=8Gb M5=06 M6=03 M7=00 M8=5F
(bootloader) cpu: MSM8953
(bootloader) serialno: ZY224BLVMC
(bootloader) cid: 0x0032
(bootloader) channelid: 0x40
(bootloader) uid: B5E66CBA00000000000000000000
(bootloader) securestate: flashing_unlocked
(bootloader) verity-state: enforcing
(bootloader) iswarrantyvoid: yes
(bootloader) max-download-size: 536870912
(bootloader) reason: Last time flashing failed
(bootloader) imei: *****************
(bootloader) meid: 
(bootloader) date: 07-29-2017
(bootloader) sku: XT1710-09
(bootloader) battid: SNN5983B
(bootloader) iccid: 
(bootloader) cust_md5: 
(bootloader) max-sparse-size: 268435456
(bootloader) current-time: "Sat Jan  3 17:37:25 UTC 1970"
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[0]: motorola/albus/albus:7.1.1/NPSS26.
(bootloader) ro.build.fingerprint[1]: 118-19-18/24:user/release-keys
(bootloader) poweroffalarm: 1
(bootloader) ro.build.version.full[0]: Blur_Version.26.261.24.albus.reta
(bootloader) ro.build.version.full[1]: il.en.US
(bootloader) ro.build.version.qcom: LA.UM.5.6.r1-03800-89xx.0
(bootloader) version-baseband: M8953P_23.33.07.34R ALBUS_EMEADSDS_CUST
(bootloader) kernel.version[0]: Linux version 3.18.31-perf-gf3fa6ef (hud
(bootloader) kernel.version[1]: soncm@ilclbld83) (gcc version 4.9 201501
(bootloader) kernel.version[2]: 23 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT T
(bootloader) kernel.version[3]: ue Dec 5 00:03:05 CST 2017
(bootloader) sbl1.git: git=MBM-NG-VC0.C7-0-ge9cd975
(bootloader) rpm.git: git=5578f74
(bootloader) tz.git: git=MBM-NG-VC2.06-0-g82f94af-dirty
(bootloader) devcfg.git: git=MBM-NG-VC2.06-0-g82f94af-dirty
(bootloader) keymaster.git: git=MBM-NG-VC2.06-0-g82f94af-dirty
(bootloader) cmnlib.git: git=MBM-NG-VC2.06-0-g82f94af-dirty
(bootloader) cmnlib64.git: git=MBM-NG-VC2.06-0-g82f94af-dirty
(bootloader) prov.git: git=MBM-NG-VC2.06-0-g82f94af-dirty
(bootloader) aboot.git: git=MBM-NG-VC0.C7-0-gb6d4956
(bootloader) qe: qe 1/1
(bootloader) frp-state: no protection (77)
(bootloader) ro.carrier: reteu
all: listed above
Finished. Total time: 0.034s
```

Comment: Did you ask in the forum thread you got the tutorial from? This is a very common Moto flashing issue, as downgrading is not supported and you need a newer version of the stock firmware image (must be the same or newer than installed on your device) and by just glancing over the logs shown, you are likely trying to flash the wrong factory image for your device. I highly suggest going back to XDA and reread the thread and post there.

Comment: @acejavelin Did already, no replies.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `fastboot getvar all` and mask out IMEI and any other personally identifiable information.

Comment: @acejavelin Alright, I will do it when I get home.

Comment: @acejavelin Done.

Comment: Your bootloader is properly unlocked, you need a ROM image newer than NPSS26.118-19-18/24 for the XT1710-09, if you can't get one the same version or newer it won't work... Often this can be corrected by just skipping bootloader & gpt.bin, but you cannot relock that way. In your image file should be file called "flashfile.xml" with a little reading into it,will give you the version and proper commands to flash without locking.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your device has upgraded his android version and doesn't let you downgrade.
So, the TWRP error 255 it seems like you wanted to flash a 64bit rom on an 32bit recovery.
Try to find a stock Oreo image or flash the 64bit twrp.
If I find something I will edit this message.
P.S. No, your device isn't bricked, there is no OS installed :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=1322778262904007189
It really helped me with the problem